# Style line color and thickness in qgis python api version 3.18

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a shape file with contours, and I would like to style the major contour lines with different color and line thickness than the minor contour lines. In the attribute table I've made a column called 'MAJOR' where the cell values are 1 if the corresponding contour elevation linestring, the 'Level[m]' column, is a major contour level and 0 if not. I can then use that to style it manually using the qgis GUI. However, I have a python script that makes a qgis project and loads the shape file into it, and I would like that script to also style the lines according to the value in the 'MAJOR' column (one color and thickness where the MAJOR cell is 1 and another where the MAJOR cell is 0. I'm struggling to find out how to do this. Is there anybody that can help me with this? Here is the function that loads the shape file:

```
def Add_Layer(project, layerNode, myDestinationNode):
    bErr = False
    sErr = ''
    myLayerFileHandle_1 = None
    myLayerFile_1 = '../Dir1/Shp1.shp'
    project_folder = os.path.dirname('C:/Data/QGis Prj/File1.qgs')
    layer_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(project_folder, '../Dir1/Shp1.shp'))
    myLayerFileHandle_1 = QgsVectorLayer(layer_file, 'Shp1.shp', 'ogr')
    if myLayerFileHandle_1:
        if 'MAJOR' in shp_layer.fields().names() and 'Level[m]' in shp_layer.fields().names():
            ?? What to put here to style the lines (color and line thickness) ??
        project.addMapLayer(myLayerFileHandle_1, False)
        myDestinationNode.addLayer(myLayerFileHandle_1)
        layer_path = myLayerFileHandle_1.source()
        layer_relative_path = os.path.relpath(layer_path, project_folder)
        project.writeEntry(myLayerFileHandle_1.id(), 'dataSource', str(layer_relative_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not changing the style based on something that you're passing to your function, consider just creating a (saved) style file on your filesystem, and loading it. For example:

```
styleFile = 'C:/Data/QGIS/contours.qml'
myLayerFileHandle_1.loadNamedStyle(styleFile)
```

This assumes that your shapefile has consistent fields (which based on your question, seems to be the case).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where your `shp_layer` variable comes from as you have not defined it in your function. However, to achieve what you are aiming for you need to build a categorised renderer. You can use the following function and call it within your function that adds the layer, by replacing the line

```
?? What to put here to style the lines (color and line thickness) ??
```

with

```py
make_categorized_renderer(YOUR_LAYER)
```

###### Function

```py
def make_categorized_renderer(layer, fieldname='MAJOR', values=[0, 1], colors=['blue', 'red'], widths=[0.7, 1.4]):
    # instantiate a new categorized renderer
    cat_renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer()

    # define the field used by the categorized renderer
    cat_renderer.setClassAttribute(fieldname)

    # define categories
    categories = []
    
    for i,val in enumerate(values):
        # instantiate a new renderer category
        cat = QgsRendererCategory()

        # set label and value of category
        cat.setLabel(str(val))
        cat.setValue(val)
        
        # define symbology
        sym = QgsLineSymbol()
        sym.symbolLayers()[0].setWidth(widths[i])
        sym.symbolLayers()[0].setColor(QColor(colors[i]))
    
        # set the category's symbol
        cat.setSymbol(sym)

        # pass category to the renderer
        cat_renderer.addCategory(cat)

    # apply the renderer to the layer
    layer.setRenderer(cat_renderer)

    # propagate changes to the QGIS GUI
    layer.emitStyleChanged()
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

###### Result

[image]